# Отображение выпадающего списка admin Python Django

Tags: python, django

Разбираюсь с админ панелью Django.

Не могу понять как изменить отображение выпадающего списка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя модель:

```
# Наименование единицы измерения
class EuRashet (models.Model):
 name=models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Единица измерения')
 desc=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Описание ЕД')
 class Meta:
  verbose_name_plural='Единица измерения'
  verbose_name='Единица измерения'

# Наименование и описание выполняемых работ
class NameRashet (models.Model):
 name=models.TextField(verbose_name='Наименование работ')
 desc=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Описание работ')
 eu=models.OneToOneField(EuRashet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 class Meta:
  verbose_name_plural='Наименование работ'
  verbose_name='Наименование работ'
```

admin.py

```
# Регистрация модели наименования работ
class RashetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'desc', 'eu')
    list_display_links = ('name', 'desc', 'eu')
    search_fields = ('name', 'desc', 'eu')

admin.site.register(NameRashet, RashetAdmin)

# Регистрация модели наименование единиц измерения
class EuRashetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'desc')
    list_display_links = ('name', 'desc')
    search_fields = ('name', 'desc')


admin.site.register(EuRashet, EuRashetAdmin)
```

не смог разобраться какой настройкой регулируется это в admin.ModelAdmin.

Подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Наименование единицы измерения
class EuRashet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Единица измерения')
    desc = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Описание ЕД')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Единица измерения'
        verbose_name = 'Единица измерения'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# Наименование и описание выполняемых работ
class NameRashet(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(verbose_name='Наименование работ')
    desc = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Описание работ')
    eu = models.OneToOneField(EuRashet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Наименование работ'
        verbose_name = 'Наименование работ'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```